# If $G$ is two-ended finitely generated group, than $G$ is virtually $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometric-group-theory

I am trying to prove that every two ended finitely generated group is virtually $\mathbb{Z}$. My first idea is to find an element $g\in G$ such that $\mathbb{Z} = <g>$.

$e(G) = 2$, so there is a compact subset $K$ of Cayley graph of $G$, $\Gamma$, such as $1\in K$, and $\Gamma\setminus K$ has two unbounded components $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$. Let $g\in G$ and $|g| > 2\cdot\hbox{diam}(K)$. WLoG $g\in\Gamma_1$. Now I want to show, that

$\Gamma_1\supset g\Gamma_1\supset g^2\Gamma_1\supset\ldots$.

I tried to show this for every $|g|> 2\cdot\hbox{diam}(K)$, but obviously this is not true. How to choose $g$?

Maybe I need to consider group action on $Ends(G)$ but I don't know how to
define it.

Comment: can I ask what means a "two-ended group" ? and "virtually" means "isomorphic" ?

Comment: virtually means, that $G$ has a subgroup of fine index, witch is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, two-ended group means, that $|Ends(G)| = 2$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups

Comment: You're basically asking for a special case of Stallings ends theorem. Although there might be some conceptual shortcuts in proving this special case, the basic ideas are the same in the special case as in the general one. I would suggest just reading through a proof of the general case, for instance in the Scott-Wall paper "Topological methods in group theory", and as you read impose the special hypothesis that $G$ has $2$ ends in order to see what special conclusions follow.

Comment: What book are you reading? Try to follow the hints in Bridson-Haefliger, it is pretty much straightforward (and much easier than the general case of the Stallings' theorem).

Comment: Meier's book [Groups, Graphs and Trees 
An Introduction to the Geometry of Infinite Groups](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/groups-graphs-and-trees-introduction-geometry-infinite-groups?format=PB) has a nice proof using, essentially, set theory.